# different ylabel for each subplot in pandas.DataFrame.plot()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subplot

I have a data frame `df` with two columns: `df['A']` and `df['B']`. I am plotting my dataframe with `df.plot(subplots=True)`. This produces a figure with two subplots, one for A and one for B.
Is there a way to use the `ylabel` keyword to assign different ylabel values to the two subplots? I tried with `df.plot(subplots=True,ylabel=['A','B'])` and hoped that the first element of the list was assigned to the first subplot and the second element to the second subplot. However, the labels of both subplots are set to `'[A,B]'`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to plot a ylabel per subplot using pandas DataFrame plot function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31760509/how-to-plot-a-ylabel-per-subplot-using-pandas-dataframe-plot-function)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the axes handles returned by `df.plot`:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 3], "B": [2, 4, 1]})

axes = df.plot(subplots=True)
axes[0].set_ylabel("label1")
axes[1].set_ylabel("label2")
plt.show()
```